# AWS S3 bucket encryption - bucket property setting vs. bucket policy setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created an AWS S3 bucket and in property, I have enabled "Default encryption". Then Do I have still need to create a bucket policy similar to below?

Note I just want to make s3 encrypted in a general way, do not have very special requirement.

```
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DenyIncorrectEncryptionHeader",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket_name/*",
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
            }
        }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To test this, I created a bucket and activated **Default encryption**.

When I then tried to **upload a file via the Management Console**, it said:

> If this bucket is setup for default encryption, S3 will encrypt objects as per bucket settings.

[image: Default encryption]

The file I uploaded *did* get encrypted.

I then **uploaded a file via the AWS CLI**:

```
aws s3 cp foo s3://my-bucket/
```

The uploaded file *was* encrypted.

However, please note that the setting is called **Default encryption**. This means that, unless otherwise specified, the object will be encrypted. However, **it does not enforce encryption**, so if a user specifically selected a *different type* of encryption (eg MKS instead of AES256), they would be allowed to do so. (I could not see a way they could specifically request 'no encryption'.)

This is where your policies (above) come in. They can enforce a specific form of encryption. If those requirements are not met, then the `PutObject` is denied.

I then took the encryption policies from [How to Prevent Uploads of Unencrypted Objects to Amazon S3 | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-uploads-of-unencrypted-objects-to-amazon-s3/) (which seem to match the ones you used) and put them in a **Bucket Policy**.

I then tried to upload from the management console **and it failed!** It only worked if I specifically chose "Amazon S3 master-key" as the encryption option. Therefore, the "Default encryption" option is not compatible with the policies.

I also tried uploading with "AWS KMS master-key" as the encryption option and **it failed again** because this does not match the policy (which specifically checks for AES256, not KMS encryption).

**Bottom line:** Using *Default encryption* will cause objects to be encrypted in some way. The policies can enforce a specific type of encryption.

Comment: Another note: The S3 condition key `s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption` was available long before the "Default encryption" option for buckets was introduced.  Formerly, this was the only way to ensure that stored objects were encrypted -- by requiring it to be specified when the object was uploaded.

Comment: Thanks John Rotenstein for testing and explaining. My observation was: if I only set "default encryption", then using AWS CLI I can: aws s3 cp hello.txt s3://bucketname (or download from bucket name to local) without setting --sse AES256, while if I set bucket policy, then I need to use:  aws s3 cp hello.txt s3://bucketname --sse AES256. so I was confused, is the file really encrypted by using only default encryption? if the file is already encrypted, then why do I need to have a bucket policy?

Comment: John Rotenstein: I do not understand what is your conclusion. by enable default encryption and set to S3 master-key, S3 will encrypt file for you using s3 master-key way (I guess AES256). if you set AES256 in bucket policy, S3 will still encrypt for you using AES256. the only difference for me is when I type AWS CLI, I need to set --sse AES256 in the case of bucket policy is set. while if bucket does not have bucket policy, then I do not need to indicate --sse AES256

Comment: Thanks Michael - sqlbot. From what you said, looks like bucket policy and default encryption setting are a kind of duplicate. maybe I only need to have default encryption enabled.

Comment: @john-rotenstein : so, shall I say policy is evaluated before default encryption settings ??